# Can not select an element from the auto complete list using css selector

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to identify an element for an automcomplete list. The css selectors that I have used are

```
.tt-dataset-airports>span.tt-suggestions p

or
.tt-dataset-airports>span.tt-suggestions>.tt-suggestion p

List<WebElement> departureList=null;
        departureList=aDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".tt-dataset-airports>span.tt-suggestions p"));

       departureList.get(0).click();
```

However, I am unable to select the element from the list. The error is 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

The code is

```
<div class="tt-dataset-airports">
<span class="tt-suggestions" style="display: block;">
<div class="tt-suggestion">
<p class="" style="white-space: normal;">
Any London 
<span class="pull-right"/>
</p>
</div>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Look for the text instead if you have to use CssSelector. Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034929/how-to-locate-an-element-by-value-using-css-selector-in-webdriver)

```
By.cssSelector("td[class='someclass'][value='unique text']");
```

Or, xpath does a nice job too if you write it the follosing way

```
//p[.='Any London']
```

Comment: Sorry your solution didn't work for me. As I used the following code, but the element was not located from the auto-complete drop down list (By.cssSelector("td[class='tt-dataset-airports'][value='Any London']"))