# how to locate an element by value using css selector in webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

For the following element, how to find it by the value of the td using css selector? In this case it's "unique text"

```
<td class="someclass" colspan="3">
   unique text
</td>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use something like this,

With CSS Selector,

```
 By.cssSelector("td[class='someclass'][value='unique text']");
```

For more information on using css selector, [See here](http://seleniumtestautomationtipsandtricks.blogspot.in/2013/01/finding-elements-using-class-selector.html)

Comment: @saifur If you're looking to find an element by its value(unique text) you need to find where it is, in this case it is inside a 'td' which has a specific class(some class)

Comment: This would only work if you actually had an attribute called "value" on your <td>-node. There is no value selector in CSS.

Answer (score 5):

We can create a XPath something like the below:

```
//td[contains(text(), 'unique text')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following XPath always gives me expected result and performance. See my another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019752/select-an-element-by-the-text-it-contains-with-selenium-webdriver/25020114#25020114)

```
//td[.='unique text']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the CSS method to locate the element by its class name.

```
css=".someclass"
```

See more examples [here.](http://www.testingexcellence.com/css-selectors-selenium-webdriver-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

> WebElement element =
> driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='value to be taken']")); //This line is to select Radio Button
>
> element.click();

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the WebElement either using dynamic xpath or dynamic css

css-

```
WebElement css = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td#someclass"));
```

xpath-

```
WebElement xpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[text,'unique text']"));
```